# How do I delete a certain field in a different table when the user deletes his account?

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, reference, laravel-jetstream

I have a problem when a user deletes his account, but a list that he created still exists, how do I delete the list when the user deletes his account?
I use jetsream laravel for auth.

The following is the list table that I want to delete based on the email to be deleted:

[image: image.png]

and the following is the users table that you want to delete:

[image: image.png]

I have tried reading the [jetsream docs](https://jetstream.laravel.com/), but still can't find a solution, please help friends.

Comment: You can use `onDelete('cascade')` in the migration for database engines that support `cascading`, otherwise you can hook into the [`deleted` or `deleting` lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545995/delete-related-models-in-laravel-6-7) of you eloquent models to manually delete relationships.

Comment: do u want to delete other records as well oh need to stop deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving the lists of a user in another table, then you just need to take the user id as a foreign key in the lists table and use onDelete('cascade') on that list table.

For example:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
->on('users')>onDelete('cascade');
```

When a user will delete his account, then the associated data with his account will also be deleted in the list table.

Comment: do i have to do this in the same migration? or create a new table migration?

Comment: You have to do this in the same migration. Just add a new column of user_id as foreign key in the table where you are saving the users other information.

Comment: will the user id be automatically filled in?

Comment: No. You have to pass the user id value in that table.